# operand should contain 1 column Use Variables in SQL statement in Python

Tags: mysql, python

Trying to insert four columns and multiple rows with variables.
The table in mysql has 8 columns in total.

Four columns to insert is as following:

```
report_type= tuple(("ada","asda","frfe","adaaa","adaddd","fdgg"))
request_id = tuple(("12532532","22532432","3253263","424323","243255","6234532"))
situation = tuple(['IN_PROGRESS_' ]* len(request_id)) 
country =tuple(['us']* len(request_id))
```

The module I'm using is pymysql, and python version is 2.7
inserting code is as following：

```
sqlstr ="INSERT into info_request(request_id,country,report_type,situation) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)" 
cursor.execute(sqlstr, (request_id,country,report_type,situation))
```

These query supposed to be work, but It returns Internalerror: (1241, u'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
I searched on this error for the whole day, but still can't solve it. 
Please help.